# Mapping table Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, mapping

I'm trying to do kind of a vlookup in Access.

This is the input table [PROFILE]:

```
Name  Age  Position  Experience   Country 
Will  24   Manager   2 years      China
Bill  46   Director  5 years      United States
```

Now, when I select fields from this table as a query, I need to update the country name with the country codes. I have a table with all the country codes called [Country Codes].

[Country Codes] Table:

```
Country Code     Country Name
CN               China
US               United States
UK               United Kingdom
IN               India.... and so on
```

So, my query on the above table should look like:

```
Name  Age  Position Country
Will  24   Manager  CN
Bill  46   Director US
```

My query right now looks like this:

```
SELECT [PROFILE].NAME, [PROFILE].AGE, [PROFILE].POSITION, [PROFILE].COUNTRY
FROM [PROFILE];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     PROFILE.NAME
   , PROFILE.AGE
   , PROFILE.POSITION
   , [COUNTRY CODES].[COUNTRY CODE]
FROM PROFILE INNER JOIN [COUNTRY CODES]
ON   PROFILE.COUNTRY = [COUNTRY CODES].[COUNTRY]
```

If it is your desire to update your table, the query will be different. Check [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/update-data-by-using-a-query-HA010076527.aspx) for more information on doing update queries in Access. If this is a one time change from storing the country name to storing the country code data in your profile table, use an update query to change it. If your profile table should always store the country name, but you need to see the country code in some circumstances, don't run any update, but use the above query to get the code instead of the name.

Comment: Do you just want to see the country code in your query results or do you want to change the country in the profile table to the country code. I can't quite tell from your question. The above query just shows the results, it doesn't change anything in the table.

Comment: I want to update the country with the country code in the profile table and also show the code in the query